# gsap menu to scroll to elements only moves down as expected, not up

Tags: javascript, gsap

I've got a page using `gsap` to animate scrolling.

To navigate, the menu is setup with a simple "scroll to ID" approach which is intercepted by gsap to do the scrolling.

This works as expected to scroll down the page, but not up the page. However if you've scrolled down the page, selecting the element above from the menu doesn't scroll up. But selecting an element 2 up from the current one, then scrolls up 1 element.

An example of the code;

```html
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section id="section1" class="panel">
  </section>
```

```js
gsap.utils.toArray("nav a").forEach(function(a) {
    a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        gsap.to(window, {duration: 1, scrollTo: e.target.getAttribute("href")});
    });
});
```

A demo is [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/marksweb/pen/PobgMEd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logical issue. Once you've scrolled past a section, the element has been moved down by 100vh. So when you navigate to its y offset, it's 100vh below where it was at the start.

There are different ways to fix it. The easiest may be to keep an array of values of the original offset and scrollTo those values instead. [Demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/xxRNdwP?editors=0010).

Sides notes:

- You can just use the selector strings as your targets in GSAP when you don't need it scoped further.
- You should use a double colon (`::`) for pseudo-elements in CSS.
- If you're going to use ES6 features like `const` some places, you might as well use them throughout your code.
- You're more likely to get help even quicker in [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!